# Help understanding Power Automate send email to function

Tags: power-automate, send-email, variable

I am new to Power Automate and have successfully set up several flows that work as expected...almost.  My flow ends with sending an email.  I'd like to have a single email go to a recipient noted in the record (which can vary) and to a set email inbox (always the same).  The prompt in the To line says that additional recipients can be added by using ";" between entries.  So, I added an Initialize Variable to pull the record recipient and inserted that output to the "To" line in the send an email action, however when I then add "; nextemail@email.com" the send email action ignores the variable output result and only sends the email to the 2nd address.  The variable is pulling correctly because if I remove the 2nd address, the email is sent to the record recipient.  I even tried adding the 2nd address to the "cc" area but again, whenever a 2nd address is included, the action ignores the variable recipient.

My work around has been to break out the actions into two (1 send an email action for the record recipient and 1 for the 2nd address) but this doesn't give the end user the same information that it would if they could see both recipients in the same email.

I'm at a loss as to why this behavior is occurring. I have also begun looking into the possibility of appending the variable recipient to include the 2nd address (so that the output includes both) but so far my searching for this action speaks to pulling multiple email addresses from a single field and joining together, while in my case I will always have only 2 recipients (the one from the record and 1 constant).

Happy to share screen shots if helpful, just let me know which components would be needed to troubleshoot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The power of posting...decided to continue searching and came across a post that eventually led me to the answer.

In the end, I added another Initialize Variable that used the concate() function.  This allowed me to add my static (constant) email and insert the other variable output so that a single output would be used in the "To" line.  Not sure if it is a true statement or not, but it does seem as if a static and dynamic output cannot be entered on the same line.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/How-to-add-both-a-static-email-address-and-a-dynamic-content-to/td-p/636346